# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE and the meaning of \A and \Z

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, stored-procedures

I came across code similar to the following in an Oracle stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM hr.employees WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME, '\A'||:iValue||'\Z', 'c');
```

And I am not sure what the \A and \Z do.

From what I can glean from the Oracle documentation, I think that they simply suppress the meaning of special characters in the iValue parameter. If so, the above must be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM hr.employees WHERE FIRST_NAME=:iValue;
```

Can anyone confirm this? Empirically this seems to be the case.

I think that in the past they wanted case insensitive searching so the 'c' was an 'i' before. So in this case we do not need to use the REGEXP_LIKE function any more and can replace it with an equals.

Answer (score 1):

- `\A` matches the position at the beginning of the string.
- `\Z` matches the position at the end of the string **or** before a newline at the end of the string.
- `\z` matches the position at the end of the string.

These are independent of multiline mode, unlike `^` and `$`.

Example:

`foo\Z` would match on `foo\n`, but `foo\z` would **not** match on `foo\n`.

See [Oracle reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012).

---

if `||` is used for string concatenation, then it's not the same as simple string comparison as it would allow you to use regex. (Also I'm not sure how Oracle treats case sensitivity when using `=`, MySQL ignores case by default when comparing strings.)

Comment: Oracle is always case sensitive when comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

`\A` matches the very start of input.
`\Z` matches the very end of input.

Check out [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), which is a great regex resource

Comment: Have done so, thanks. It also says there that "\Q...\E Matches the characters between \Q and \E literally, suppressing the meaning of special characters". Do they mean Q and E or is that just an example?

Comment: They mean `\Q` and `\E` so for example `\QQuick*-.\/\E` Will match `Quick*-.\/`.

Comment: To put it another way, the regex `foo(\Q+-*/\E)` is equivalent to `foo(\+\-\*\/)`.  The `(` and `)` still form a group, but the characters that were between the `\Q` and `\E` lose whatever special meanings they normally have.